# Caching strategy

Tags: java, networking, cache

I was making a simple currency converter utility and had to cache the conversion factors after fetching from server. Came up with the below interface. I have basically delegated the caching responsibility to OkHttp itself. Review appreciated.

```
public interface CurrencyConverter {

    Interceptor CACHE_CONTROL_INTERCEPTOR = chain -> chain.proceed(chain.request())
                                                          .newBuilder()
                                                          .header("Cache-Control", String.format("max-age=%d, max-stale=%d", 3600, 0))
                                                          .build();

    OkHttpClient HTTP_CLIENT = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .cache(new Cache(new File(System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir")), 1024 * 1024 * 10))
            .addNetworkInterceptor(CACHE_CONTROL_INTERCEPTOR)
            .build();

    BigDecimal getConversionFactor(String currencyFrom, String currencyTo) throws IOException;

    BigDecimal convert(String currencyFrom, String currencyTo, BigDecimal value) throws IOException;
}
```

The server is 3rd party and sends a no-cache header which I think does not make sense. It should be safe to cache conversion factors for some duration.

Answer (score 1):

It makes perfectly sense to make that not cachable. You want the result based on the actual exchange rate, and this changes every second.

What I really don't like: Your interface has a HttpClient and is therefore coupled to implementation. This should be moved to the actualy implementation.

The next thing: You're caching is also coupled to the technology. So if the backend changes, let's say you get it from a database, the caching mechanism is not reusable. I think it's okay for your case, and I wouldn't bother too much,... but, if you consider testing, you actually can't unit test the caching.

Comment: Good points, can't really argue there. Thanks for the feedback !